# Append JavaScript Object in HTML without library

Tags: javascript, html

I have a object that looks like this:

```
var options1 = {
    container: 'carosello',
    fetchCard: function(chunksize) {
        //function that returns (chunkSize) card objects to be displayed in the carousel
        return {
            image: 'https://images.blablabla',
            title: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ',
        };
    }
};
```

And I want to be able to display each item in the object in HTML like this:

```
<div id="carosello">
   <div class="caroselloCard">
      <img src=" image here " alt="">
      <p> title here </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

All this only with javascript without the help of **NO LIBRARY.**

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? `.createElement()`, `.textContent`, `.setAttribute()`, `.src`, ...

Comment: Repost of [Display JavaScript Object in HTML without library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62103539)

Comment: _"it was in the example of the exercise that was **assigned to me**, **I** should create a reusable carousel component "_ - _"I"_ does not mean _"the folks over at StackOverflow"_

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector` is enough for this

```js
var options1 = {
    container: 'carosello',
    fetchCard: function(chunksize) {
        //function that returns (chunkSize) card objects to be displayed in the carousel
        return {
            image: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/688/100/100.jpg',
            title: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ',
        };
    }
};

document.querySelector("p").textContent = options1.fetchCard().title;
document.querySelector("img").src = options1.fetchCard().image;
```

```html
<div id="carosello">
   <div class="caroselloCard">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```